# calling map on a collection after it has been returned vs chaining map using the dot

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

This works as expected:

```js
    let responses = await Response.find({
      responder_id: req.user._id,
    }).populate({ path: "query_id", select: ["query_type", "content"] });

    responses = responses.map((response) => {
      return response.query_id;
    });
```

But the below does not:

```js
    let responses = await Response.find({
      responder_id: req.user._id,
    })
      .populate({ path: "query_id", select: ["query_type", "content"] })
      .map((response) => {
        return response.query_id;
      });
```

The only thing that I can think of is maybe it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of these functions.

Comment: use `.populate().exec().map()` this should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority is not as you think it is. What is being awaited is not `Response.find(...)`, but `Response.find(...).populate(...)`. With this in mind, here's the way to write it in the second form correctly (with the only difference being a pair of parentheses):

```
let responses = (await Response.find({
  responder_id: req.user._id,
})
  .populate({ path: "query_id", select: ["query_type", "content"] }))
  .map((response) => {
    return response.query_id;
  });
```

However, some re-indenting would be needed to make this readable. The first snippet might be easier to read anyway.